# JsonModule not loading when all Tapestry jars are outside of web war

Tags: tapestry

I'm experimenting project structure and using latest Tapestry version 5.4.1. I tried moving jars from outside of the WEB WAR and into the classpath.

Getting below error while starting the app.

[localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart Exception starting filter app
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception loading module(s) from manifest jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/MyProject/Shared/lib/main/tapestry-json-5.4.1.jar!/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF: Failure loading Tapestry IoC module class org.apache.tapestry5.json.modules.JSONModule: Module class org.apache.tapestry5.json.modules.JSONModule contains unrecognized public methods: public static void org.apache.tapestry5.json.modules.JSONModule.provideCoercions(org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.Configuration).
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.IOCUtilities.addModulesInManifest(IOCUtilities.java:123)

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure loading Tapestry IoC module class org.apache.tapestry5.json.modules.JSONModule: Module class org.apache.tapestry5.json.modules.JSONModule contains unrecognized public methods: public static void org.apache.tapestry5.json.modules.JSONModule.provideCoercions(org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.Configuration).
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.RegistryBuilder.add(RegistryBuilder.java:162)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.IOCUtilities.addModulesInList(IOCUtilities.java:137)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.IOCUtilities.addModulesInManifest(IOCUtilities.java:107)

I thought it should work.Can someone please take a look and suggest?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I identified the issue, we have multiple Tapestry webapps and I was concentrating one one and not on others in the same tomcat which seems like mixing with classpath jars and then jars in web-inf/lib in other webapp. When I removed the jars from others web-app then at least this issue did not occur. I've further issues but not related to this question. I'm going to experiment more